# open social embeded experience

Tags: ibm-connections, ibm-sbt

I've developed an iWidget that creates a status update with an open social embeded experience gadget but it's not working.

This is the open social part data that I send to the server:

```
"openSocial": {
    "embed": {
        "gadget": "http://questionmine.com/app1/design/template/widgets/openSocial.xml?__dev_proxyPolicy__=intranet_access&__dev_policySet__=GADGET_TRUSTED%2CGADGET_SSO&__dev_appContexts__=EMBEDXP",
        "context": {
                    "communityid":"urn:lsid:lconn.ibm.com:communities.community:' . $key . '",
            "id": "' . $_POST['project'] . '",
                            "video":"' . $video . '",
                            "design":"' . $design . '",
                            "headline":"' . $headline . '"
        }
    }
```

}

This has worked before on another connections server, do I need to do any extra settings to allow the gadget ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there is a file called opensocial-config.xml

For instance on the Deployment Manager it may be... 
/local/con/opt/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/profiles/Dmgr01/config/cells/localhostCell01/LotusConnections-config/opensocial-config.xml

```
<developer enabled="true" allowSSOFeature="true" allowIntranetProxyAccess="true">
    <developer-hosts-whitelist allServers="true">
    <!-- 
        List of base URLs that are allowed to publish 'developer-mode' gadgets
        <host url="http://{host.com}/base/url/1" />
                            ...
        <host url="http://{another.host.com}/base/url/N" />
     -->
</developer-hosts-whitelist>
</developer>
```

You want to switch to true enabled allowSSOFeature allowIntranetProxyAccess
also switch whitelist AllServers to True

Edit the /local/con/opt/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/profiles/AppSrv01/config/cells/localhostCell01/LotusConnections-config/opensocial-config.xml

Restart your Connections Server

It should come back up and enable all gadgets posted to render as EE

Comment: Just to add to Paul's answer... Please don't do this on a production server! If you need to post an EE on a production server, you should register it through the Homepage administration page.

Comment: David you are right. you'd normally execute the register method

Comment: @DavidMcMullin do you know how to troubleshoot these gadgets in a production environment ? Development is working fine but running the same on production does NOT result in an embedded experience. Is there a (was console) trace setting that you can recommend ?

Comment: @mpjonker, make sure that the gadget is in the trusted list.

Comment: @PaulBastide thanks, the only place I know of is the Homepage Administration screen where I can edit this Open Social Gadget. There the checkbox for trusted is selected. Is there another place where I can check and/or add this gadget to the trusted list.

Comment: in the opensocial-config.xml there is a spot for adding the trusted url pattern

Comment: change opensocial-config.xml to <developer-hosts-whitelist allServers="true">